# How do replication agents enable NOT FOR REPLICATION mode?

Tags: sql-server-2000, replication, sql-server-2012

How do triggers/identity columns/check contrains marked as [`NOT FOR REPLICATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237102%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) get bypassed when the user connecting is a *"replication agent"*?

---

If i am an SQL Server replication agent, and i connect to a server to perform replication, how do i indicate to SQL Server that i **am** a replication agent, so that *not for replication rules* are enabled on all tables?

Why am i asking?

Because (choose one):

- to expand the limits of human knowledge and understanding
- because i'm writing my own replication system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is done internally using sessionproperty():

```
declare @is_replicationagent bit
select @is_replicationagent = convert(bit, sessionproperty('replication_agent'))
```